# showConfig module not working - magento

Tags: xml, magento, module

I followed this tutorial
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-2-the-magento-config

When I run the URL, its does not show the Config, not working. below is my code.

config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Magentotutorial_Configviewer>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Magentotutorial_Configviewer>
</modules>
<global>
    <events>
        <controller_front_init_routers>
            <observers>
                <Magentotutorial_configviewer_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Magentotutorial_Configviewer_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkForConfigRequest</method>
                </Magentotutorial_configviewer_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_init_routers>
    </events>
</global>
```

Magentotutorial_Configviewer.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Magentotutorial_Configviewer>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Magentotutorial_Configviewer>
</modules>
```

Observer.php in Model

```
 <?php
class Magentotutorial_Configviewer_Model_Observer {
    const FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG = 'showConfig';
    const FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT = 'showConfigFormat';

    private $request;

    public function checkForConfigRequest($observer) {
        $this->request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();
        if ($this->request->FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG === 'true') {
            $this->setHeader();
            $this->outputConfig();
        }
    }

    private function setHeader() {
        $format = isset ( $this->request->FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT ) ? $this->request->FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT : 'xml';
        switch ($format) {
            case 'text' :
                header("Content-Type: text/plain");
                break;
            default :
                header("Content-Type: text/xml");
        }
    }

    private function outputConfig() {
        die( Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode()->asXML() );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it displaying the anything from observer.php. Have you tried a simple "echo" over there ?

Comment: no i didnot tried echo anything, where should write echo statement....
and observer should display xml file which have all configuration.

Comment: where are you exactly looking for output @user2088794 ?

Comment: now its giving this error

XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://local.hagentools.com/?showConfig=true
Line Number 1, Column 2: <?xml version="1.0"?>
-^

Comment: are you looking output at any URL or where can you tell me.

Comment: here i try to get output... http://local.hagentools.com/?showConfig=true     while domain is on virtual host

Comment: i think the problem is here. FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG . When I replace the FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG with {self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG}  . its gives the above mentioned error.

Comment: ` public function checkForConfigRequest($observer) {
        $this->request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();
        if ($this->request->FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG === 'true') {
            $this->setHeader();
            $this->outputConfig();
        }
    }`

Comment: Welcome actually I was trying to guide you where things are going wrong. Glad to see you find out by yourself.Cheers !!!

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below so the question is removed from the unanswered list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not closing the config tag, which will cause Magento to flop over. Similarly, in your module declaration the config tag isn't being closed as well.

The below with the closed tag should work:

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Magentotutorial_Configviewer>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Magentotutorial_Configviewer>
 </modules>
<global>
  <events>
    <controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers>
            <Magentotutorial_configviewer_model_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Magentotutorial_Configviewer_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>checkForConfigRequest</method>
            </Magentotutorial_configviewer_model_observer>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>
   </events>
 </global>
</config>
```

And module declaration:

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Magentotutorial_Configviewer>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Magentotutorial_Configviewer>
  </modules>
</config>
```

You can check to see if the module is running through using (place it in your declared method):

```
Mage::log('message');
```

Using an echo or var_dump within an observer unless using a particular event for a renderer tends not to show anything. Logging is the way forward for backend projects.

It will appear in your system.log in var/logs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove space in front of opening